# django model property depended on request.session value

Tags: django, session, request

My models have validation_range field. Very complex. For simplicity I will show example - it may looks stupid but this is for explanation only - so don't look at the model itself, please

```
class Person(models.Model):
    validity_range=DateTimeRangeField(default=(None,None))

class PersonData(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    validity_range=DateTimeRangeField(default=(None,None))
```

And now Person can have a two names: E.g. Miss Eva Smith born 1.1.1980 gets married 22.03.2022 and becomes Mrs. Eva Novak.

(for simplicity I omit time part of validity_range)

So datas look like:

```
Person{id:1,validity_range:(1980-01-01,None)}
PersonData{id:1,person_id:1,first_name:'Eva',last_name:'Smith',validity_range:[1980-01-01,2022-03-22)}
PersonData{id:2,person_id:1,first_name:'Eva',last_name:'Novak',validity_range:[2022-03-22,None)}
```

I preserve context_date in request.session['context_date'].

And I will show Eva's full name dependent of request.session['context_date']

```
def index(request):
   person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
   context ={
      'person' : person,
      'context_date' : request.session.get('context_date')

   }
html_template = loader.get_template('index.html')
return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

html:

```
Context_date is: {{ context_date }}

At that date Person no {{ person.id }} was called {{ person.person_data.first_name }} {{ person.person_data.last_name }}
```

Of course this is wrong, because person_data is a set not a object.

I thought to make a property in model:

```
  class Person(models.Model):
        validity_range=DateTimeRangeField(default=(None,None))
        @property
        def first_name(self, date):
            try: 
               person_data =PersonData.objects.get(validation_range__contains=date) #We can assume, that validation_ranges don't overlaps (database constraint)
               return person_data.first_name
            except PersonData.DoesNotExist:
               return None #oups - there's no persondata in that date!
```

But how pass parameter in template?

Answer (score 0):

Very ugly solution:

```
{% with person.persondata_set|context_filter:context_date as user %} {{person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }} {% endwith %}
```

and templatetags/filters.py

```
@register.filter
def context_filter(queryset, date):
    return queryset.filter(validity_range__contains=date).first()
```

I hope, that someone finds something better...